# Very tricky piecewise function problem...

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, piecewise-continuity

[image]

Just looking for a starting point on this question thank you!!! So if the limit as $x$ goes to $-\infty$ is $7$ then we are dealing with the top part of the function???

Comment: what is your problem squenshl? why do you think it is very tricky?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to+\infty}r(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{E(x^2+5)}{2^x-F}+G=G$. Therefore, $G=2$.

Comment: For $\lim_{x\to-\infty}r(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{(Bx^A-5)(8x-C)(x-4)}{(x-3)(x^2-D)(2x-16)}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{(Bx^A-5)(8x-C)}{(x-3)(x^2-D)}$ to exist and be different from $0$ we would need the degree of the numerator and denominator to coincide. Then $A=2$.

Comment: To have a vertical asymptote at $x=5$ we would need $2^{5}-F=0$. Therefore, $F=2^5=32$.

Comment: To have a vertical asymptote at $x=-7$ we would need $x^2-D$ to vanish at $x=-7$. Therefore, $D=49$. Since we don't want a vertical asymptote at $x=3$, the the factor $x-3$ must cancel. Then, wither $C=24$, or $D=5/9$.

Comment: Note there is a mistake in my second comment. I cancelled $x-4$ with $2x-16$. Those should stay there. The conclusion is the same, though.

Comment: In order to get $7$ as the limit then $B=7/4$.

Comment: How would we find $E$?

Comment: I got $E=32/21$.

Answer (score 0):

From $\lim_{x\to-\infty} r(x)=7$, you can deduce a couple of things:

- The degree of the numerator & denominator must be the same; otherwise, the limit would be $0$ if the denominator had greater degree / $\infty$ if the numerator had greater degree
- You already have a degree of $4$ in the denominator, so that means to get a degree of $4$ in the numerator, you have to have $A = 2$.
- In the limit as $x\to-\infty$ you will have to end up with something like $7x^4/x^4$ if you want to get a limit of $7$. The constants and the terms of lesser degree will vanish in the limit. This gives you a hint about what the coefficient on the $x^4$ term will have to be in the numerator, in order to get $7$.

For the other parts of the problem - you can only get a vertical asymptote at some $x=k$ if you have a term like $(x-k)$ in the denominator (or something else where plugging in $x=k$ will cause the whole denominator to be $0$), that does not get cancelled out in the numerator - because, if it gets cancelled, you will just have a removable singularity.

And to make the whole function continuous, you will need
$$
\lim_{x\to 4^{+}} r(x) = \lim_{x\to 4^{-}} r(x)
$$
i.e. the limit of the first piece, approached from the left, has to be the same as the limit of the second piece, approached from the right.